# Why is this parameter not used?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In Backbone 1.1.2, at line 279

```
// Return a copy of the model's `attributes` object.
toJSON: function(options) {
  return _.clone(this.attributes);
},
```

options is clearly not used, so why have it there at all.  It is just wasted memory.

What am I missing here?

Per comment here is one way of calling this code -so why pass options when it will not be used?

```
toJSON: function(options) {
  return this.map(function(model){ return model.toJSON(options); });
},
```

Comment: [backbone issue: toJSON function's parameter misleading](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/1410)

Comment: which brings up pretty much the same question - why pass an argument to a parameter that is never used?

Comment: It does not really waste that much memory, remember that it is passed by reference, but still, that parameter obviously shouldn't be there.

Comment: @user3293653: Did you even bother reading the link t.niese posted and the links to the other issues linked there? It clearly states why the options parameter is there.

Comment: Think about what such a comment would look like: "this function is passed a parameter 'options' which can be used by overriding methods".  I think however way you word it, it is awkward and potentially confusing.  Whereas, just putting the parameter in there makes the meaning perfectly clear in a concise way.  Also, you seem to be insisting on a downside vis a vis "memory usage", but you haven't really explained how that would be significant or even real.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't waste memory, since the argument would have to be available as `arguments[0]` anyway (either options is a function call and the vm has to do it for side-effects anyway, or it's just an object and so it's just a reference).

It also serves as a document reference to what superclasses can implement.
Since JS is using prototypes for its object orientation, if you create a `toJSON` function in one of your superclasses, it'll be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

There's no functional reason for including that in the `Model.toJSON` signature -- it is strictly for developers' benefit.

From the [link that @t.niese uncovered](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/1410):

> Morning @aoboturov! Thanks for pointing this out. It's actually intentional and is meant to remind you that collection.toJSON(options) passes along the options argument to each of its models by default. See #1222 and #1098 for details.

<sub>(Note that the referenced [#1222](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/1222) is basically just a dupe, and [#1098](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/pull/1098) is where they added the feature in the first place.)</sub>

In other words, the parameter is put there for the sake of clarity for developers who may want to override the `Model.toJSON` implementation.  The collection passes along the original `Backbone.sync` call's `options` object, since some implementations of `Model.toJSON` might want to use it.

Including that `options` parameter in the signature doesn't affect memory usage at all (even if it did, the effect would be miniscule), since the `Collection.toJSON` implementation passes that options object as an argument, either way.

Comment: You're using a framework. Having a parameter that's not referenced in the body (but has to be in `arguments` anyway) is basically nothing.

Comment: @user3293653 Wether it should br a comment or not is up to the API developer and their coding guidelines. I would call it good practice to have it actually as a real parameter. There are many other things that would really waste memory (especially when passing different objects to the same function).

Comment: @user3293653 it really doesn't waste any memory.  Without knowing any details about Javascript engines, Ven's answer looks correct to me -- that argument is present is any case as `arguments[0]`.

Comment: @user3293653 ironically the absence of the `option` parameter could even increase the memory usage. As the JS engine may compile it first without a parameter and then when called with one parameter it may need to compile a second version accepting one parameter (then having both functions in memory). This for sure is not likely in this situation, but it may happen.